# How can I change the Input request stream

Tags: input, stream, request

I want to change the input request stream.

Detail is:

I want to replace the 'Text 1' in the Input stream to 'Text 2'

The first: I use the Request.Filter as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.filter.aspx But this way I can only replace a byte data by an other byte, I can not replace a string by a string and I also can not change buffer size. I need to access and replace the old buffer by an other byte array (content and buffer.length)

The second: I try to use a ISAPI Filter, but It seem that the IIS 7 and above is no longer support for SF_NOTIFY_READ_RAW_DATA. I google and result is I should write a native HttpModule with CHttpModule::OnReadEntity event. Is it right ?

I would be very appreciate if you can tell me how I can change the input request stream.

Thank you very much.

Huy

Comment: I found that we can use the native HttpModule as following artice:http://forums.iis.net/t/1157522.aspx. I try to update the ContentType-Length, and EntityBody (use InsertEntityBody) but it haven't run for me. :(

Answer (score 0):

I debugged and see that We will catch twice times per one request.

if I only read the entity body, then insert again, don't make any change, the second request will have exactly content and request run well. The source code as following:

// Retrieve the request body.
            hr = pHttpRequest->ReadEntityBody(
                pvRequestBody, byteCount, false, &byteCount, NULL);
    pHttpRequest->InsertEntityBody(pvRequestBody, byteCount);

if I read the entity body, then replace 'ngo+duc+huy' by 'ngy+van+qua' (this is successful), the second request will have wrong content. This request have some strange content as: 'ÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝÝ'

so, the request haven't run property. The source code as following:

// Retrieve the request body.
            hr = pHttpRequest->ReadEntityBody(
                pvRequestBody, byteCount, false, &byteCount, NULL);
size_t found(0);
            string requestContent = static_cast(pvRequestBody);

            found = requestContent.find("ngo+duc+huy");
            if(found !=string::npos)
            {
                requestContent = 
requestContent.replace(requestContent.find("ngo+duc+huy"), sizeof("ngo+duc+huy") - 1, 
"ngu+van+qua");
            }

```
        pvRequestBody = (void*)requestContent.c_str();<br />
pHttpRequest->InsertEntityBody(pvRequestBody, byteCount);<br />
```

you can download my simple solution at: http://www.4shared.com/file/OJr8GFJQ/HelloWorld_2.html